# How to reload user defined tag in CMS Made Simple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cmsmadesimple

I have a html file which loads a list from my database and allows the front end user to remove a particular entry.

The HTML Code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function sendForm() {
var dataSend=$("#clientid").val();
$("#responseDiv").html("<h2>Removing from Database...</h2>");
$.post("RemoveClient.php",{
ClientId: dataSend
},function(data) {
$("#responseDiv").html(data);
$("#clientlist").empty();
$("#clientlist").html("{client_list nocache}");
});
return false;
}
// ]]></script>
</p>
<div id="MainForm"><form class="form" onsubmit="return sendForm()">
<h2 class="formstyle">Client Wizard</h2>
<p>Please fill all the required fields.</p>
<div id="clientlist">{client_list nocache}</div>
<p><input style="font-size: 1.5em; font-color: #000000;" onclick="sendForm()" type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
</form>
<div id="responseDiv"> </div>
</div>
```

The UDT called for {client_list} is given below.

```
$dbhost='127.0.0.1';
$dbuser='user';
$dbpass='pass';
$dbname='dbname';
$conn=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if(!$conn)
{
die('Could not connect:'.mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql="SELECT clientid,clientname FROM client order by clientid"; 
echo "<label> Select Client: </label>"; 
echo "<select id=clientid name=clientid>"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
echo "<option value=".$row['clientid'].">".$row['clientname']."</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>";
```

Now, once I click on delete, I want the drop down list to refresh with the new list not having the deleted client. I tried doing that by emptying the div and then reloading the UDT. Unfortunately this does not seem to be working, the way I want it to, as the list does not get refreshed until and unless I refresh the page. Is there anyway I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The quick/easiest option would be to assign it an id and to remove the entry via javascript.

Second, would be to have RemoveClient.php return it as part of the response from the AJAX.

`var response = data.split('|');
$("#responseDiv").html(response[0]);
$("#clientlist").html(response[1]);`

Third, I would strongly advise against this way but it is the question you ask, put the UDT alone on new page then load the page with the ?showtemplate=false parameter.

`$("#clientlist").load("//www.mydomain.com/myudt.html?showtemplate=false");`